# Bind visibility of element to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, document-ready

I want to have an element visible only if another element's value is not empty.

Right now I'm doing this using:

```
function setReceiveSmsNotificationsCheckboxArea() {
  var checkbox = $('#ReceiveSmsNotifications');
  var value = !!$('#Cellphone').val().trim(); //bool depending on txt val
  checkbox.prop('checked', value);
  checkbox.closest('.form-group').toggle(value);
}

$('#Cellphone').change(function () {
  setReceiveSmsNotificationsCheckboxArea();
});

$(document).ready(setReceiveSmsNotificationsCheckboxArea);
```

Is there a way to combine the two latter functions to one (so that the change even runs on startup as well?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the change event on page load in order to trigger the handler

```
function setReceiveSmsNotificationsCheckboxArea() {
  var checkbox = $('#ReceiveSmsNotifications');
  var value = !!$('#Cellphone').val().trim(); //bool depending on txt val
  checkbox.prop('checked', value);
  checkbox.closest('.form-group').toggle(value);
}

$('#Cellphone').change(setReceiveSmsNotificationsCheckboxArea).change();
```

Comment: What does the final `change` do? I mean, what does the `change` function return? Is it like fluent API? Can I also use `checkbox.prop('checked', value).closest('.form-group').toggle(value);`?

Comment: `checkbox.prop('checked', value).closest('.form-group').toggle(value);` will work

Comment: @Arun Isn't it change event required to be wrapped in doc ready? just curious to know if it is fine as is.

Comment: @Jai depends on where the script is kept... from what OP reported the current script is working so we can assume it is after the element

Comment: @Shimmy the last `.change()` will trigger a change event which will invoke all the registered change handlers.. and yes it will support the fluent api...